# Stream web radio and choose via Smartphone app

Tags: radio

the question could sound trivial, but I'm super new in the Raspberry world. I searched a lot in the internet for this problem, but I wasn't able to find an "easy" solution.

I've a raspi 3 with Raspbian installed and what I want to do is to stream webradio on the raspberry (via aux) and choosing the radio channels via smartphone.

I understand I've to install a software that converts the raspi in a multimedia server and then via IP and port connect an app to it.

I installed mopidy, volumio and kodi. But with no one I was able to set up the system.

Is there a simple package (I'd avoid to compile software if possible) to install via apt?

Someone has faced this problem and has a workflow?

p.s. I tried to set up Kodi but I wasn't able at all to activate PVR add ons. After adding them all of them run forever to 0%.

Thanks to all

Comment: If you want an easy solution, you have to stick to what someone else already did. If you have an idea of your own, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I'll definitely get with an easy solution. But as said I could't find a straightforward walk through.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I think perhaps you can do this with Kodi on the Pi, and a Kodi remote app on the phone, such as [Kore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kore&hl=en_GB).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but I have a lot of problems with PVR installation, none if working and adding radio channels.

Comment: That would be useful information to edit into your question, to prevent people making suggestions you have already tried.  I don't understand what "none if working and adding radio channels" means, but perhaps the problems you are having can be resolved?

Comment: Ok solved partially by burning Volumio distro and running it into the raspie. Not able to find alternative apps to the official volumio one, but still working fine